# Add a new index to multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array.

ie.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [item_name] => x

        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [item_name] => y

        )

)
```

I need a way to add a new index to that array .

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [item_name] => x
            [value] => 1

        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [item_name] => y
            [value] => 1
        )

)
```

The value may/may not remain the same throughout.

One way to implement this is to loop the array and insert the new index `value`.

My question is that is there any other better way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: `array_walk_recursive`

Comment: [`array_walk`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) should be sufficient, since this is only a 2D array.

Comment: example with array_walk_recursive?

Comment: There are many ways to possibly do this, but a loop is the most straight forward thing you can possibly do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), you can use [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
array_walk($array, function(&$a) {
  $a['value'] = 1;
});
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using an older version of PHP, I should really have mentioned that [`anonymous functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), such as the above, will only work with `PHP 5.3 >`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $arr is your array and `$yourval` is the value to be stored as the new array element. You can do it as follows.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
     $arr[$i]['value'] = $yourval;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);//Will display the new array
```

Comment: You are welcome @user1584103
Plz mark it as correct answer if you got the output..